# t-sql editing the procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm learning sql and asp.net and trying to make a first simple web-shop,I have a good working procedure, but I'm trying to edit it, apply a 'select' to tblProducts to filter products by type:

```
SELECT * FROM tblProducts where PCategoryID=1
```

But I can't understand how to change my procedure to do it, all my attempts leads to syntax errors

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcBindAllProducts]
AS
 SELECT A.*, B.*,C.Name, A.PPrice-A.PSellPrice as DiskAmount, B.Name as ImageName,C.Name  as BrandName 
  from tblProducts A
 inner join tblBrands C on C.BrandID=A.PBrandID 
 cross apply(
 SELECT TOP 1 * from tblProductImages B where  B.PID=A.PID order by B.PID desc 
 ) B 


 RETURN 0
```

**Only one way** to do it without sintax errors but  result of this procedure are 2 tables, one with filtration by type, and one with inner join

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcBindFilteredProducts]
AS

 SELECT * from tblProducts where tblProducts.PCategoryID=1
 SELECT A.*,B.*,C.Name, A.PPrice-A.PSellPrice as DiskAmount, B.Name as ImageName,C.Name  as BrandName 
  from tblProducts A  
 inner join tblBrands C on C.BrandID=A.PBrandID 
 cross apply(
 SELECT TOP 1 * from tblProductImages B where  B.PID=A.PID order by B.PID desc 
 ) B 


 RETURN 0
```

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. . . _"all my attempts leads to syntax errors"_ . . . without posting the errors

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful if you could provide more information about the syntax errors your experiencing.

If you've already created the [dbo].[ProcBindFilteredProducts] procedure then you will need to either :

- Alter the procedure (simply replace the CREATE word with ALTER
- Drop the procedure before calling create again "DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcBindFilteredProducts] GO"

Usually its easier to alter.

Comment: I dont have the new procedure, just want to edit the old one adding additional select , I hope I understand it right